# How to detect new fields added in cloud firestore function onUpdate()

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I would like to know if it's possible to detect when a new fields is added on a document with cloud functions. 
I store all my friends in a single document with this structure :

```
- userId
    - friends_sub_collection
        - friendsListDocument
            friendId0 (HashMap<String, Object>)
               "status": "friend_request",
               "date" : 1583448203,
               ...
            friendId1
            friendId2
            ...
```

I know that i can get the changes in cloud functions with something like :

```
.onUpdate((change, context) => {

  const newValue = change.after.data();

  const previousValue = change.before.data();
}
```

But since my fields are documentId i can't check if they exists with something like `newValue.friendsFieldId`

My suggestion will be to store all ids in an array of the document `allFriendsId`, then check the difference between the old and new array and then get the right field.

Is there any better ways ?

Thanks for the suggestions and your time.

Comment: This is a standard javascript problem related to comparing two JS objects.  There's nothing special about cloud functions or firestore here.  There are lots of things you can search for and implement.

Comment: Yeah you are totally right sorry, thanks for the answer.